# initializing an array from objects makes NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, object, exception, nullpointerexception

I want to set some data in array from objects, here is class A, it cause an NullPointerException. Why? how to solve this? what is the problem with my initializing?

```
class A {

    int a;

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

public class ObjArry {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    A[] ObjectArray = new A[5];

    ObjectArray[0].setA(10); //Exception occurs in this line
    ObjectArray[1].setA(9);
    ObjectArray[2].setA(8);
    ObjectArray[3].setA(7);
    ObjectArray[4].setA(6);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exception will occur on all other lines, too.
By default, the newly initialized array `new A[5]` is empty, i.e., all its fields are `null`.
You first have to do something like:

```
ObjectArray[0] = new A();
ObjectArray[1] = new A();
ObjectArray[2] = new A();
ObjectArray[3] = new A();
ObjectArray[4] = new A();
```

Comment: Or, better, provide a constructor with a parameter, so you can construct and set the value in one go.

Answer (score 1):

[JLS §10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) states that

> [...] each component of the (newly created<sup>1</sup>) array is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).

<sub>(<sup>1</sup>The comment was added by me.)</sub>

Looking at [§4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), we find that

> For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is `null`.

In consequence,

```
A[] ObjectArray = new A[5];
```

creates an array of length 5 and each cell contains a reference to `null`.

So the answer is: It happens because the JLS says so.